# spread of fock state distribution and infinite revival time of rabi oscillation in spontaneous emission

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-electrodynamics, atomic-physics, cavity-qed

In cavity QED for a 2-level atom, the revival time for oscillation b/w the states $\left|\ e\ 0\right\rangle$ and $\left|\ g\ 1\right\rangle$ (absorbing the same photon that is emitted) is said to be infinity because in general, Rabi oscillation revival time is proportional to the square root of the mean of the occupancies of Fock states. Why should the spread of the Fock states distribution go to large values or close to infinity in the spontaneous emission case, to make the revival time infinity ? Refer :- http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v94/i1/e010401 for a description of Rabi Oscillations Revival